# Generate random numbers in specific range

Tags: matlab, random, statistics

I want to generate Gaussian random numbers in MATLAB for long program which runs for many number of iterations.  I used randn function, but is there a way to avoid negative results and generate random numbers in range from 1 to 100.

For example

X=0.02*randn;

How Can I get only positive values in specific range.

Comment: If you want the number to be between 1 and 100, it won't be a Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 4):

As Cheery wrote, a Gaussian distribution covers the whole real set, so there is no way to have numbers both normally distributed and limited in support.

A solution might be to truncate the values: regenerate the values when `randn` returns a value outside of the desired range.

This can be implemented quite easily (and naively) by the following code:

```
function x = randnlimit(mu, sigma, minVal, maxVal, varargin);

assert(mu>=minVal && mu<=maxVal);
assert(sigma>0);

x = mu + sigma*randn(varargin{:});
outsideRange = x<minVal | x>maxVal;
while nnz(outsideRange)>0
   x(outsideRange) = mu + sigma*randn(nnz(outsideRange),1);
   outsideRange = x<minVal | x>maxVal;
end
```

**edit** to summarize the discussion @Cheery and I had:
You can choose: either you get a Gaussian, but then you are stuck with values that cover the whole real axis (so also negative values). On the other hand, if you need a limited range, you need to use a different distribution to generate samples from.

Which approach you need depends on your application. Whether the need for a limited support is primordial or the shape of the pdf is the most important.

The code I provided above will be limited to the range `[minVal, maxVal]` and approximately gaussian when you choose `sigma` and `mu` appropriately, i.e. `mu = maxVal/2 + minVal/2` and `n * sigma = maxVal - minVal`. For a value of `n` larger than two, the distribution will be quite close to a real Gaussian. E.g. for `n=2`, I expect only 5% difference (for `n=3`, less than 1%). You can of course specify `minVal = 0` and `maxVal = +Inf` to select the positive values only.

Comment: "A solution might be to truncate the values" - this will break the distribution!!! From programming point of view it is not a problem, but from the mathematical - a serious one.

Comment: You are right that it will not be Gaussian. I explicitly wrote that it is impossible to have both Gaussian and a pdf that has a limited support. This truncation method is just an effort at making random values that have a bell-shaped pdf over the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

A Gaussian distribution by definition has a distribution of (-inf, inf). The standard deviation (sigma) is 1 by default. If you're looking for a uniform distribution over [1, 100]
use 99*rand()+1 or randi([1 100]) for integers.

ps: for Gaussian distribution with range there is a solution (by setting the sigma and shifting maximum of the distribution)
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/156521

```
function X=random_generator(n, x_max, x_min)
    X=[x_min+((randn(n,n)).*(x_max-x_min))];
end
```

x_min here is not the minimum value - it is the average value (or the peak of the distribution). Distribution is symmetrical with respect to x_min. But negative values would not be removed as distribution defined on the whole X axis. Their probability will be smaller.

pps: from Matlab's manual

> Generate values from a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard
>   deviation 2: 1 + 2.*randn(100,1);

Comment: This code will NOT generate normally distributed samples. It will generate uniformly distributed samples over a scaled interval. No distribution with limited support can be a real Gaussian, but that code you cited from your source doesn't even come close.

Comment: @Egon Geerardyn  why not? sigma is set to (x_max-x_min) and distribution is shifted by x_min (which is mu or average value in the normal distribution). FYI! (from the Matlab manual)

Generate values from a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard deviation 2:
r = 1 + 2.*randn(100,1);

Comment: Because if x ~ Uniform(a,b) (read: x is uniformly distributed over  [a,b]), then c*x ~ Uniform(a*c, a*b) and c + x ~ Uniform(a+c,b+c) for all constants a,b and c. The function `rand` returns uniformly distributed samples. You can verify this for yourself by generating lots of samples and plotting its histogram. This will be quite a constant empirical pdf, certainly not bell-shaped.

Comment: @Egon Geerardyn  I cited the Matlab manual with example. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html

Comment: The function you copied from your reference mentions `rand`, not `randn`. With `randn`, it indeed produces samples from a normal distribution with a clumsily specified range (as stated in the manual). But that will NOT prevent from generating negative samples. It is impossible to have both an exact Gaussian and limited support.

Comment: @Egon Geerardyn Sorry )) I was checking distribution right now and exactly was wondering why there is square ) No, I understand, of course, that it is not possible to limit it, but cutting the values will also break the model where this distribution is used by the author of the question. I think we need more information from him why does he want to use this one in specified range. Sorry for misunderstanding (or error in copying)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7008/discussion-between-egon-geerardyn-and-cheery)

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a limited support distribution that have the desired properties, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions. I have a similar problem I want to apply finite mixtures model to a limited support distribution, unfortunately, most of the algorithms focus on Gaussian distributions.